# How does "Reference to an object" plays a role in Dynamic method dispatch in a case where a method in Parent class is Protected?

Tags: java

I'm confused with the behavior of java run time polymorphism in conjunction with protected access modifier. I have a class named A in package `Pack1` as follows:

```
package Pack1;
public class A{
    protected void m1(){
        System.out.println("A's implementation");
    }
}
```

and a child class named C in package `Pack2` as follows:

```
package Pack2;
import Pack1.*;

class C extends A{
    public void m1(){
        System.out.println("C's implementation");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a1 = new C();
        a1.m1();
    }
}
```

Now, if `m1()` was public in parent class it would not give any error calling `m1()` with parent's reference from within child class, but in this particular case where `m1()` is protected it gives error saying:

> m1() has protected access in A.(after all being Protected, m1() should be accessible in class C)

Could someone kindly help me to grasp the logic involved here ?

Answer (score 0):

By making the type of `a1` `A` you can only access members of the `A` class, unless they are overridden in the child class as in:

```
class C extends A{
    @Override
    public void m1(){
        System.out.println("C's implementation");
    }
```

This would cause the `m1` method in class `C` to be called when an instance of `C` is accessed as an `A`.

You can make the access modifiers equal to or less restrictive as the base. As shown in your example where it changes from `protected` to `public`.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime system is following the restrictions you've given it, going with that it knows based on the type you're actually operating with. Polymorphism and access modifiers are really fairly separate. So if you have an 'A', and you're not in 'A''s package, then you can't call its 'm1' method. But, if you can cast an 'A' to a 'C', because it really is a 'C', then you can call the same 'm1' method after casting to a 'C', because 'C''s definition says that 'm1' is public.

Think about it the other way...if it mattered what the access level was of A.m1 when calling it through a C reference, then the JVM wouldn't be able to know if it could make that call or not because it can't know in general what is behind that C reference. It can only work with what instructions it has on C's versions of the method.

This is why you can't go the other way around. It can't be that C's m1 is private and yet A's m1 is public. That would let you call call C's m1 through a reference to an A, even though C doesn't want you to do that, since the JVM can't know better. So this has to be disallowed at compile time.